# Exercise problems in Arnold's ODE concerning direction/vector fields under diffeomorphism

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am stuck with some problems in Arnold's Ordinary Differential Equation. In Page 75, Problem 5, Arnold asked

> Can a diffeomorphism of the plane map the direction field of the differential equation $\dot{x}=x^2$ into a field of parallel lines?

and offers an

> **Answer.** It is possible, though an explicit formula is difficult to write out.

But I can't see why it's possible. The diffeomorphism needs to map the line $x=0$ to some line $\ell$ in the plane. Since $x=0$ is the asymptote of the integral curves of $\dot{x}=x^2$, while the image of these curves are a collection of parallel lines. So $\ell$ should be the asymptote of these parallel lines, which means they are all the same line, a contradiction.
What's wrong with my reasoning above? And why is it possible to find the diffeomorphism? Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Additional problem.** Our ODE class has specified Arnold as the textbook, but unfortunately, our teacher seems to be not so good at presenting the ideas in the book clearly. To make things worse, exercises in Arnold's book frequently seems confusing(may partly due to translation, which makes sentences unsmooth), and our teacher never explains those exercises. So I'm wondering whether there are sources available about the solution of problems in Arnold's ODE. I googled with no relevant results. Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 4):

The flow of the differential equation provides part of the solution. Here
$$
\phi(x;y_0)=\frac{y_0}{1-xy_0},
$$
as it represents the solution curves as images of segments of the lines parallel to the $x$ axis.

The complication arises as you now have to find a reparametrization that eliminates the singularities at $x=\frac1{y_0}$.

Comment: Thanks:) But how to eliminate the singularities? According to my reasoning in the question it's not even possible to do that.

Comment: Your reasoning is faulty, as that would also apply to $y'=y$ where the flow map $ϕ(x;y_0)=y_0e^x$ provides directly a global diffeomorphism.

Comment: Oh I see! I abused continuity to obtain invariance of asymptote under diffeomorphism. Thanks for your example! But is there a fast way to show the existence of such reparametrization, since Arnold mentions this without giving any hint?